# Open Mapping Theorem and the Bounded Inverse Theorem to show $T^{-1}$ is not bounded

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, normed-spaces, compactness, open-map

### Preface

This is a problem in my Functional Analysis course. I'm really struggling to dissect part (b) any help/alternative solutions would be greatly appreciated on both parts of the question :)

---

### Question

Let X be the space of continuous functions $x : [1,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb R$ which have compact support, that is there exists a compact interval $I_x$ of $[1,\infty)$ such that $x(t) = 0 \quad \forall t ∈ [1,\infty) \backslash \space I_x$. Consider X with
the norm $\left\lVert x \right\rVert = \max_{t\in[1,\infty)}
|x(t)|$ and define the mapping $T : X \rightarrow X$ as
$(Tx)(t) = \frac{1}{t^2}x(t)$,for every $t \in[1,\infty).\\$

(a) Show that T is linear, bounded, bijective and find $\left\lVert T \right\rVert$ and $T^{-1}$ and show that it is bijective.
\begin{aligned}
\forall x_{1}, x_{2} \in X \space \text{ and }\space \alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R} \\
T\left(\alpha x_{1}+\beta x_{2}\right)(t) &=\frac{1}{t^{2}}\left(\alpha x_{1}+\beta x_{2}\right)=\alpha \frac{1}{t^{2}} x_{1}+\beta \frac{1}{t^{2}} x_{2} \\
& = \alpha\frac{1}{t^{2}} x_{1}(t)+\beta \frac{1}{t} x_{2}(t)\\
&=\alpha\left(T x_{1}\right)(t)+\beta\left(Tx_{2}\right)(t). \\ \text{Hence T is linear.}
\end{aligned}

\begin{array}{l}
\text { Note: } 0 \lt \frac{1}{t^{2}} \leqslant 1 \quad \forall t \in[1, \infty) \\
\Rightarrow \quad \frac{1}{t^{2}}|x(t)|=\left|\frac{1}{t^{2}} x(t)\right| \leqslant|x(t)| \quad\forall t \in[1, \infty) \\
\text { i.e }\|T x\|=\left\|\frac{1}{t^{2}} x(t)\right\|=\max _{t_{t}(1, \infty)}\left|\frac{1}{t^{2}} x(t)\right| \\
\leqslant \max _{t \in[1, \infty)}|x(t)|=\|x\| \\
\therefore T \text { is bounded }
\end{array}

as for finding $\left\lVert T \right\rVert$ and showing that $T^{-1}$ it is bijective I am unsure how to do this :/

(b) The next problem I have is showing that $T^{-1}$ is not bounded and to explain why this not in contradiction with the Open Mapping Theorem and the Bounded Inverse Theorem

Comment: $T$ multiplies $t^{-2}$ to each functions. What is the inverse operation (to cancel that $t^{-2}$)?

Comment: $T^{-1}=t^{2}x(t)$ ?

Comment: Yes. Now you need to check if it is bounded.